# PL/SQL function with laravel

Tags: laravel, plsql

I have to implement packages with PL/SQL in Laravel.

This is the PL/SQL

```
FUNCTION GET_ROW (p_table_name IN VARCHAR2, p_field_name IN VARCHAR2, p_field_value IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  l_consult       VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_result      SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  l_consult := 'SELECT * FROM ' || p_table_name || ' WHERE ' || p_field_name || ' = :1';
  OPEN l_result FOR l_consult USING p_field_value;
  RETURN l_result;
END;
```

So to implement in laravel that function

```
$table_name = "USER_TOKENS";
            $field = "USER_ID";
            $value = 3;
            $cursor = [];
            $cursor = DB::select("BEGIN result := GET_ROW(:table_name, : p_field_name, :p_field_value); END;",
                    [
                        'table_name' => $table_name,
                        'p_field_name' => $field,
                        'p_field_value' => $value,
                        'result' => $cursor,
                    ]);
```

But what I get is the following:

```
"message": "oci_bind_array_by_name(): Argument #4 ($max_array_length) must be greater than 0"
```

Why is this? I know that the function returns a cursor. But is the cursor the row?